# Change location for man pages

Tags: language-support, locale, manpage

Until Ubuntu 18.04, if you wanted to change the man pages location, you just have to execute something like this (depending on the desired language you wanted, in this case, spanish):

```
sudo apt install manpages-es manpages-es-extra
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

The problem is if you use a newer version of Ubuntu (>18.04), because the `manpages-es` package doesn't exist.

How could I resolve this?

Comment: Is this not what you need? https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/manpages-es

Comment: that's for `bionic` release

Comment: Yes that is what 18.04 s code name is. Top right it has link for 3 releases.

Comment: Yes, I aprreciate your help, thanks! But I would like to do it in a 20.10 relase, for example. I know I can get that file visiting that URL, but not with a simple `apt install` :(

Comment: No looks like you may need to do a little work to get them.

Comment: Isn't the package obsolete? Packages should provide their own manpage translations (in `/usr/share/man/es` for example) and the selection should be automatic depending on the user's locale. See for example [localization of man pages on Linux (Ubuntu)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43384/localization-of-man-pages-on-linux-ubuntu)

Comment: The package works, but it is not included in newer distros like focal or groovy